# withScroller using angular-datatables results in TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am using angular-datatables and want to use the scroller extension. The example requires me to add an option `withScroller`. This gives me an error. I am using `requireJS` and I have confirmed that `scroller.js` is loaded. It still results in this issue.

I also get exception TypeError: Cannot read property `aDataSort` of undefined

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please show some code, so people have a chance to figure out your problem. You can click "edit" and then add the code you are struggling with to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, because I had a typo in the HTML code:

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtoptions" dt-columns="dtColumns">
```

instead of

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns">
```

Not finding `aDatasort` basically indicates that the plugin does not have a dataset to build a table on - so there might be different causes for this error as well.

Answer (score -1):

angular-datatables does not support RequireJS yet. [here](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/gettingStarted)

> Additional Notes:
>
> RequireJS is not supported.